# How to fetch data from XMLType Query using JDBC ResultSet?

Tags: xml, oracle, jdbc, resultset, xmltype

I have an XMLType query as follows:

```
SELECT
   c.CustId,
   XMLELEMENT(NAME "customer",
      XMLATTRIBUTES(c.CustId AS "id"),
      XMLELEMENT(NAME "name",c.Name),
      XMLELEMENT(NAME "city",c.City),
      XMLELEMENT(NAME "projects",
      (SELECT XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(NAME "project",
                 XMLATTRIBUTES(p.ProjId AS "id"),
                 XMLELEMENT(NAME "name",p.Name)))
      FROM Projects p 
      WHERE p.CustId=c.CustId))) AS "customer-projects"
FROM Customers c
```

And I want to fetch the data using JDBC ResultSet.
I tried

```
ResultSet result.getString("customer-projects");
```

But this gave me null.

Please help.

Comment: Which database?

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel  Oracle 11g DB.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel : Can you please help me in figuring this out. I am really struggling with this.